# iOS - auto slide UISlider to maximum value when user reached certain value

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I want to have the effect that the slider is auto sliding to maximum value if the user reach a certain value. The animation from current to maximum value is easly done but I stuck in the problem that the thumb of the slider is jaggering around cause its somehow dragged by the user but also animated by the slider value set. This is my code:

```
@IBAction func sliderChange(_ sender: UISlider) {

    if sender.value >= sender.maximumValue / 2{
        sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true, block: { timer in
            sender.setValue(sender.value + 0.01, animated: true)
            if sender.value >= sender.maximumValue{
                timer.invalidate()
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MySegue", sender: nil)
            }
        })
    }

}
```

So the `isUserInteractionEnabled` is unfortunately not working when I need it. I also tried without success:

```
sender.cancelTracking(with: nil)
```

and

```
for subview in sender.subviews{
    subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Somehow I have to cancel the touch event when the user is dragging the thumb. Does someone rebuild this behaviour or can give me an advice here?

**Update:**

Here is a quick showcase to be sure what my problem is.

[image: illustration]

Answer (score 0):

@Stephan replace your code with the following code and check as it worked for me.

```
@IBAction func sliderChange(_ sender: UISlider) {

        if sender.value >= sender.maximumValue / 2{
            sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true, block: { timer in
                sender.setValue(sender.value + 0.01, animated: true)
                if sender.value >= sender.maximumValue{
                    timer.invalidate()
                    sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                } else if sender.value < 5{
                    timer.invalidate()
                    sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                }
            })
        }

    }
```

Check this gif 
[image: GIF]

Comment: I updated my question with an illustration gif to show what my problem is. Your code is more or less the same like mine. The problem is the userInteraction which is not disabled

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. What I want to achieve is that the slider is auto sliding to the end even when the user is still holding down the touch (see in my gif the black circle around the cursor) and there is the jitter problem what I mentioned cause the slider is animating yes but the thumb is still hold by the touch event. I can even see the problem in your gif.